# React componentDidUpdate not called when needed

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a parent that will send a request for new data when it's props change.

I have a Time range selector component (Child) that will default to the last 8 weeks of data received from redux state wrapped on it. It will call a dispatch on 'timeRange' state.

Parent should then detect the 'timeRange' prop that is wrapped on itself too has changed and fire off the request. (I was hoping).

```
class Parent extends component {

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { timeRange } = this.props;
    if (timeRange !== prevProps.timeRange) {
      getData()
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.timeRange)
    // Logs the timeRange set by Child even though
    // INITIAL_STATE should have been applied to the Parent.

    return (<Child />)
  }
}


    class Child extends Component {


  componentDidMount() {

    const { availableDates } = this.props;
    /*
      logic to set dateRange on availableDates
     */
    setDateRange(newRange)

  }
}
```

Note that availableDates is retrieved by a higher order component long before Parent mounts.

Any advice on how to improve my process is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think we'll need to see more code as theres a couple functions that are called that you haven't shown. Also you don't pass any props to the child so I'm confused.

Comment: Use componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)